# Odoo keeps on loading the page for much time

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Odoo is installed on remote server, and when trying to access or upload some data, after updating data, keeps on loading for twenty minutes or so.

Anyone got any idea on this?

Comment: With upload some data you mean importing a CSV?

Comment: yes exactly, or sometimes uploading attachments,

Comment: There are a few possible reasons: hard disk transfer rate, internet connection speed, huge amount of data, etc

Comment: Go to task manager and check memory usage

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
sudo service odoo stop
sudo service postgresql restart
sudo service odoo start
```